# get xStep in onOffsetsChanged in Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, swipe, live-wallpaper, homescreen

I'm writing a LWP with a Class extends WallpaperService and an overwritten onOffsetsChanged method. When I swipe the Homescreen I'm getting the Offset and Pixel values but not the Step values (xStep, yStep). The Step values are only initiated once on start but not when I add or delete Homescreens..... I'm going crazy because it doesn't work on my Samsung Gio nor Galaxy Note.... Whats going wrong?

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258234/onoffsetschanged-not-called-by-touchwiz