# Android Live Wallpaper not working same on different mobile phones

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am trying to make my first live wallpaper. Everything was good while i was testing my app on my own mobile phone (Xperia Arc). But after running the app on G2 mini, Galaxy note 10 n8000 and Galaxy note 3, I found that nothing works.

On G2 mini the background doesn't even load, but in both notes the `OnOffsetChanged` listener doesn't do it's job.

This is the drawing part and offset listener of my project, if any other methods is needed, tell me to add.

```
    private void drawItems(Canvas c) {
        c.save();

        // item 12
        c.drawBitmap(item12Bitmap,item12Left,item12Top,null);

        // item 0
        c.drawBitmap(item0Bitmap,item0Left,item0Top,null);

        // item 1
        item1Left = nextLeftGenerator(item1Left,item1NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item1Bitmap,item1Left,item1Top,null);

        // item 2
        item2Left = nextLeftGenerator(item2Left,item2NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item2Bitmap,item2Left,item2Top,null);

        // item 3
        item3Left = nextLeftGenerator(item3Left,item3NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item3Bitmap,item3Left,item3Top,null);

        // item 4
        item4Left = nextLeftGenerator(item4Left,item4NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item4Bitmap,item4Left,item4Top,null);

        // item 5
        item5Left = nextLeftGenerator(item5Left,item5NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item5Bitmap,item5Left,item5Top,null);

        // item 6
        item6Left = nextLeftGenerator(item6Left,item6NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item6Bitmap,item6Left,item6Top,null);

        // item 7
        item7Left = nextLeftGenerator(item7Left,item7NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item7Bitmap,item7Left,item7Top,null);

        // item 8
        item8Left = nextLeftGenerator(item8Left,item8NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item8Bitmap,item8Left,item8Top,null);

        // item 9
        item9Left = nextLeftGenerator(item9Left,item9NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item9Bitmap,item9Left,item9Top,null);

        // item 10
        item10Left = nextLeftGenerator(item10Left,item10NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item10Bitmap,item10Left,item10Top,null);

        // item 11
        item11Left = nextLeftGenerator(item11Left,item11NextLeft);
        c.drawBitmap(item11Bitmap,item11Left,item11Top,null);

        c.restore();
    }
```

and the offset listener :

```
    @Override
    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,
                                 float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {

        Float diffrence;

        if (firstOffset == null){
            firstOffset = xOffset;
            diffrence = 0.0f;
        }
        else {
            diffrence = firstOffset - xOffset;
        }

        item1NextLeft = item1FirstPlace+Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*1f);
        item2NextLeft = item2FirstPlace-Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.9f);
        item3NextLeft = item3FirstPlace+Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.5f);
        item4NextLeft = item4FirstPlace-Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.8f);
        item5NextLeft = item5FirstPlace+Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.7f);
        item6NextLeft = item6FirstPlace-Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*1f);
        item7NextLeft = item7FirstPlace+Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.5f);
        item8NextLeft = item8FirstPlace-Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.7f);
        item9NextLeft = item9FirstPlace+Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.6f);
        item10NextLeft = item10FirstPlace-Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.8f);
        item11NextLeft = item11FirstPlace+Math.round(diffrence*drawHere.width()*0.5f);
        //drawFrame();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Offset Changed!!! xOffset : " + xOffset + "yOffset : " + yOffset + "xStep : " + xStep + "yStep : " + yStep + "xPixels : " + xPixels + "yPixels : " + yPixels ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //System.out.println("Offset Changed!!! xOffset : " + xOffset + "yOffset : " + yOffset + "xStep : " + xStep + "yStep : " + yStep + "xPixels : " + xPixels + "yPixels : " + yPixels );
    }
```

Comment: There's been reports about _onOffsetChanged_ not firing and/or reporting correct values on TouchWiz. Maybe it still applies ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258234/onoffsetschanged-not-called-by-touchwiz .

Comment: @harism I read that. But the thing is that i can't handle the changes with OnTouch event. I need to know that which page i am. the touched  areas doesn't help. is there any way to check offset of the page , in drawing callback instead of OnOffsetChanged listener?